# How do I resolve 'Str is not callable' error in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Any guidance is appreciated. I'm very new to programming.

Problem(s): Runtime error of 'str is not callable.' And, likely semantic error. Specifics: "if len(s) <= 70:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Intended results: I'm trying to write a function that takes a string and then prints that string so that the last letter of the string is in column 70 of the display.

What I've tried: Run code in PEP8 and it doesn't return any syntax errors. Removed original line which assigned str to s.

The code in Python 3:

```
def right_justify(s):
    '''
    (string) -> string
    takes a string named s
    places it in column 70 - len of string
    '''
    s = input("Type in a word: ")
    for len in s:
        if len(s) <= 70:
            len(s) + 70 - len(s)
    return s 

print(right_justify)
```

Comment: What do you think `for len in s` is doing?

Comment: I'm sorry, but by only looking at your code, I seriously have no idea what you're trying to do.. `for len in s` (looping the string by each character), `if len(s) <= 70` (if length of the string less than or equal to 70), `len(s) + 70 - len(s)` (does nothing), `return s` (returns the orginal input string).

Comment: Thanks for your question. I'm thinking that it is evaluating or accounting for the length of characters in s... this is what I'm trying to accomplish at least.

Comment: To clip `s` you can do: `s = s if len(s) <= 70 else s[:70]`

Comment: This doesn't answer your questions. But python strings already has a built in `rjust` method you can use. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust

Comment: `print(right_justify)` will always print out "yeah that's a function" (or something like that). What purpose does it have in your code? It will not execute the function.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments and answers. All of this is very new to me and the book that I'm using doesn't seem to be helping me understand syntax and how best to express a solution.

Comment: I'm really trying not to sound too harsh, but the example code demonstrates a lack of understanding of the very basics of Python. Thus, even if we answer your question you likely won't understand it. We'd practically have to write the book to answer at a level you can use (because we can't guess your knowledge accurately), so just start with a good beginner text like [A Byte of Python](https://python.swaroopch.com/), which is free online. If you get stuck ask on #python IRC on freenode before StackOverflow. Sorry.

Comment: @gilch You're totally right. I am very much trying to get a grasp on the basics. I will look into the suggestions you provided.

Comment: @Zuckerbrenner also, when you say " Run code in PEP8 and it doesn't return any syntax errors. " I assumen you meant you ran your code through some linter checking for PEP8 *style errors*. Note, PEP8 doesn't address syntax errors, it's a *style guide*. Things that fail a PEP8 linter can certainly be 100% syntactically correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, you want to put enough spaces in front of the string so its last character is in column 70.

You do not need to iterate over the string. This will achieve what you need. Note there is no point putting `input` within the function, because you cannot call the function with a string argument.

```
def right_justify(s):
    '''
    (string) -> string
    takes a string named s
    places it in column 70 - len of string
    '''
    if len(s) <= 70:
        output = ((70 - len(s)) * " ") + s
        return output

input_string = input("Type in a word: ")
output_string = right_justify(input_string)
print(output_string)
```

Comment: Just like user Haken Lid commented on the question, Python has a right justification method built in: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Your answer clarified a lot for me.

Comment: @Zuckerbrenner My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is:

```
def right_justify(s):
    return "%70s" % s
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the

> len variable

With something else.

len is a Python keyword sir its reserved and not meant to be use as a variable

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: That gets rid of the exception, but it doesn't make the code work.